# Visual Studio 2010 syntax highlighting for JsRender

Tags: visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting, jsrender

Is there any way to get HTML syntax highlighting working for JsRender templates (as part of an aspx file) in Visual Studio 2010?

My aspx files typically look like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jsrender.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Default.js">
</head>
<body>
    <script id="defaultTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
        <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Customername</th>
                        <th>Contact</th>
                        <th>Url</th>
                        <th>Details</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {{for CustomerData}}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{>Name}}</td>
                            <td>{{>Contact}}</td>
                            <td>{{>Url}}</td>
                            <td>Click</td>
                            <td>Click</td>
                        </tr>
                    {{/for}}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div id="navContainer">Next</div>
        </div>
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for JsRender syntax highlighting in VS 2010, but if you have VS 2012, there is a a Web Essentials plugin which adds syntax highlighting within script blocks (of type other than text/javascript). It also provides hightlighting on {{foo }} tags.

In a future release it will likely be built in...

The Web Essentials plugin download is [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6)

Update: VS 2012 and VS 2013 now include syntax highlighting for JsRender tempates.

Comment: Hello coder from the distant past, is there any way to use this syntax highlighting if you have your templates contained in external files?

Comment: @Maverick: If the external file is an ".html" file (but just the template content, no script block) then you get highlighting. You can use the approach here: http://www.jsviews.com/#compiletmpl - see Registering a template from a markup string (fetched from the server in a text file). Just make it an .html file.

Comment: I am using external `.html` files, but the syntax highlighting isn't great.

Comment: Is it different from the highlighting of a local script block template? Works well for me (VS 2013).